# One URL multiple backends in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Background:
We have got at IIS/ASP.NET website using FormsAuthentication. We need to keep several code versions running at the same time. 
Today customers will log into app.domain.com entering a customercode, username and password. Depending on the customers current version (recorded in a 
database table), they will be redirected to eg. app1.domain.com or app2.domain.com.

The problem:
The customers keep bookmarking appX.domain.com instead of app.domain.com. We therefore need to maintain app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com etc. even when 
those versions are obsolete. It is also confusing to the customers with all the different urls.

How we would like it to work:
The user should be able to log into app.domain.com and be transparently redirected to the right website or codebase, keeping the domain name 
app.domain.com.

Is this possible in IIS?

Comment: Im just curious, is there a reason you couldn't perform a 302 redirect to the correct URL?  Im thinking there are a couple ways you could go about doing this, but I imagine that once you start messing with the URL the user visits, and the content displayed, you start to get into JavaScript permission issues and such... so Im just curious why you couldn't redirect the user to the *correct* URL?

Comment: We are doing redirects  to app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com today, but the customers are bookmarking theese urls. (The number represents the version number). This means we need to maintain all the subdomains, which means a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up setting up a Apache as a proxy in front of our IIS nodes. This solved our problem.